# hide or disable MultiView Tabs from C# code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiview

I am using a multiview control for the first time to display various tools when clicking on tabbed menu items.

I am suprised by my searches this is not really possible using Asp.net / C# code-behind alone?

How do you disable a Tab in code behind if for example the Session value for UserName is not a match?

This is a C# web application.

```
<asp:MultiView ID="ToolsMultiView" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
<asp:View ID="Tab1" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        lots more code..
    </div>
</asp:View>
<asp:View ID="Tab2" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        lots more code..
    </div>
</asp:View>
<asp:View ID="Tab3" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        lots more code..
    </div>
</asp:View>
```

I also found I was not allowed to add conditional code on the .aspx page to skip an asp:View section.

Parser Error Message: A rendering block cannot be nested inside a MultiView control.

```
Line 171:            <div class="viewWrapper">
Line 172:                <asp:MultiView ID="ToolsMultiView" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
Line 173:                <%if (1 = 1) { %>
Line 174:                    <asp:View ID="Tab1" runat="server">
Line 175:                        <div class="row ">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MV1" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="view1" runat="server">
        <p>View 1 - FOR Bob's EYES ONLY</p>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="view2" runat="server">
        <p>View 2 - for everyone</p>
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

then in your Code Behind (yes there is such a thing).

```
    if (User.Identity.Name != "Bob")
    {
        MV1.Views.Remove(view1);
        MV1.SetActiveView(view2);
    }
```